# Automating ArcFM XML Export/Import

Tags: export, xml, arccatalog, arcfm

I am trying to write a script (any) that will go to ArcCatalog and then to a database and then to ArcFM XML Export to export the dataset in XML.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? Posting the code you've tried and any error messages would help us help you.

Comment: I am just trying to get an idea as to how I should proceed. I am trying to see if there is any library I can use to get to ArcFM XML Export. And I saw that Esri has - Export XML Workspace Document - function with arcpy, but I cannot find anything for ArcFM. Have you done anything regarding automating ArcFM XML Export tool instead of doing it manually? I have just been researching and wanted some clues or direction. Thank you :)

Comment: Has anybody used Wave.Extensions.Miner -Version 1.0.2 for automating this task?

Answer (score 1):

The below C# ArcObjects code snippet has worked for me for exporting ArcFM configuration to an XML document from an SDE class. I believe these are the two ArcFM library references needed:

- Miner.Interop.Geodatabase
- Miner.Interop.msxml2

```cs
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using Miner.Interop;
using Miner.Interop.msxml2;
...

// get reference to workspace
string sdeConnectionFile = @"p:\ath\to\connection\file.sde";
Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SDEWorkspaceFactory");
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(sdeConnectionFile, 0);

// reference to dataset from which ArcFM config is exported
IDataset targetDataset = (IDataset)((IFeatureWorkspace)workspace).OpenTable(datasetName);

IXMLDOMDocument xmlDoc = new DOMDocumentClass();

// manually add standard root and version elements
IXMLDOMElement rootEl = xmlDoc.createElement("GXXML");
IXMLDOMElement versionEl = xmlDoc.createElement("EXPORT_VERSION");
// don't know how to get version programatically, so setting manually
versionEl.text = "10.2.1b SP2";
rootEl.appendChild(versionEl);
xmlDoc.appendChild(rootEl);

// -- Export options from ArcCatalog ArcFM XML Export with corresponding export class --
// ArcFM Model Name Information:    MMModelNameIEClass
// ArcFM Properties:                MMFieldInfoIEClass
// ArcFM Relationship Class Info:   MMRelClassIEClass
// ArcFM Snapping Information:      MMSnappingIEClass
// Custom Object Types:             MMObjClassIEClass
// Designer Database Properties:    ?
// Domains:                         MMDomainsIEClass

// create desired config export class
IMMXMLImportExport4 importExport = new MMModelNameIEClass();
// export element and append to root
IXMLDOMElement fmConfigEl = importExport.Export(targetDataset);
rootEl.appendChild(fmConfigEl);

// write xml doc to file
xmlDoc.save(xmlFilePath);
```